# PostgreSQL Date format issue

Tags: postgresql, date

The Postgres Query `select date('22-02-2022')`
is showing Error message.

I need to save date in a column of a table, but the input date can be any format. Please suggest how to save date in YYYY-MM-DD format.
Following is the Error screenshot:

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

A `date` has no format at all. But if you specify a date *literal* (constant) the way you tried, it **has** to be in `yyyy-mm-dd` format:

```
select date '2022-02-22'
```

If you want to specify the value in a different format, use the `to_date()` function:

```
select to_date('22-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyyy');
```

If the column in the table is defined with the `date` data type, the way you specify the actually value is irrelevant as it will be stored as a binary value **without any format**.

If you need a specific format when *selecting* (displaying) those values, you can use the `to_char()` function.

Comment: No it does not. `set datestyle = 'iso,dmy';   select date '22-02-2022'; 2022-02-22`. Or  `set datestyle = 'iso,mdy'; select date '02/22/2022'; 2022-02-22`. The issue is with the `DateStyle` not matching the date/month ordering.

Answer (score 0):

If all your dates and timestamps are going to come in this way then as the `HINT` suggests you need to change the `DateStyle`.

1. Run `SHOW DateStyle`, I'm guessing it will return something like `ISO, MDY`.
2. Change it `SET DateStyle = 'ISO, DMY'`, then your example will work.

Example:

```
show datestyle ;
 DateStyle 
-----------
 ISO, MDY

select date('22-02-2022');
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "22-02-2022"
LINE 1: select date('22-02-2022');
                    ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.

set datestyle = 'ISO,DMY';

select date '22-02-2022';
    date    
------------
 2022-02-22
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable time and efforts.  set datestyle = 'ISO,DMY';  worked for me. The date format I tried were '22-02-2022', '22/02/2022', '22 Feb 2022' and '22 Feb 22' every date was converted into desired Format of '2022-02-22'

Comment: If the column you are saving to is of type `date` then it is not saved as `YYYY-MM-DD`. It will be saved as numeric value. The formatting is something external to the type itself. It is just a way to put the numeric value into a form people or other programs recognize.

Comment: I have column in Excel sheet which is having date format as 28 Feb 2022, but the C# code is reading it as 02/28/2022. How to make it read as 28/02/2022 ?

Comment: So far you have mentioned C# , Postgres and Excel. It not all clear to me what your work flow is and where and when you want  the date to be formatted?  Update your question with a complete example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There is an Excel sheet from where I have to read data and store in PostgreSQL. The Excel sheet is having Date data in "28 Feb 2022 " format. But when I read data through C# it is storing data as 02/28/2022 which is not the correct date format. It should be as 28/02/2022. Kindly suggest.

Comment: And has been pointed out to you numerous times Postgres does **not** store date formats in a `date` field. The format you see on output of the field data is the result of the `DateStyle` set in the server. In my answer and @a_horse_with_no_name 's answer you have been shown solutions to changing the output format. There is really is nothing else that can be said.